# Store a dictionary variable from Google Colab locally

Tags: python, dictionary, local-storage, google-colaboratory, pickle

In Google Colab, I have created a `dict` file names `list_dict`. How can pickle this and store it locally?

```
PATH = <LOCAL_PATH>
pickle_out = open(PATH +'<FILE_NAME>.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(list_dict, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

However, this returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-439362c7678e> in <module>
----> 1 pickle_out = open(PATH , 'wb')
      2 pickle.dump(list_dict, pickle_out)
      3 pickle_out.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

How can I store this variable locally?

Comment: Your variable `PATH` seems to be empty?

Comment: It's not actually empty. I just didn't it doesn't add any relevant information to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach works:

```
from google.colab import auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import pickle

with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(list_dict, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

#Authenticate and construct the Drive API client
auth.authenticate_user()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

file_metadata = {'name': 'data.pickle'}
media = MediaFileUpload('data.pickle', mimetype='application/octet-stream')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print(F'File ID: {file.get("id")}')
```

Then, the file `data.pickle` is stored in the root directory in Google Drive and can be downloaded from there.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```py
PATH = <LOCAL_PATH>
pickle_out = open(PATH +'<FILE_NAME>.pickle', 'wt')
pickle.dump(list_dict, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

or

```py
PATH = <LOCAL_PATH>
pickle_out = oprn(PATH +'<FILE_NAME>.pickle', 'w')
pickle.dump(list_dict, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

Comment: That gives the same error

Comment: And my second method?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It is not about the `mode` with which we open the file. Its about the connection to my local drive.